# Multiple repetitions of a regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have to search for any occurrence of `The XXth (?:and XXth)? session of the XX body` It can be any session and there are several bodies. I've come up with a pattern that finds them when they are unique in a sentence, but that fails when there is more than one repetition of that text. See an example beneath:

```py
import re
test = """1. The thirty-fifth session of the Subsidiary Body for Implementation (SBI) was held at the International 
Convention Centre and Durban Exhibition Centre in Durban, South Africa, from 28 November to 3 December 2011. 10. 
Forum on the impact of the implementation of response measures at the thirty-fourth and thirty-fifth sessions of the 
subsidiary bodies, with the objective of developing a work programme under the Subsidiary Body for Scientific and 
Technological Advice and the Subsidiary Body for Implementation to address these impacts, with a view to adopting, 
at the seventeenth session of the Conference of the Parties, modalities for the operationalization of the work 
program and a possible forum on response measures.[^6] """
pattern = re.compile(r".*(The [\w\s-]* sessions? of the (?:Subsidiary Body for Implementation|Conference of the "
                     r"Parties|subsidiary bodies))", re.IGNORECASE) 

print(pattern.findall(test))
```

This prints: `['The thirty-fifth session of the Subsidiary Body for Implementation', 'the seventeenth session of the Conference of the Parties']` and I would like to get: `['The thirty-fifth session of the Subsidiary Body for Implementation', 'the thirty-fourth and thirty-fifth sessions of the subsidiary bodies',  'the seventeenth session of the Conference of the Parties']`

I think that the problem is that the pattern is too wide, but not sure how to constrain it because I tan end in different ways...

Any clue of how to improve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is `and <NUMERAL>` after a numeral. You can use

```py
The\s+\S+(?:\s+and\s+\S+)?\s+sessions?\s+of\s+the\s+(?:Subsidiary\s+Body\s+for\s+Implementation|Conference\s+of\s+the\s+Parties|subsidiary\s+bodies)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EzWKWa/1).

*Details*:

- `The` - a fixed string
- `\s+\S+` - one or more whitespaces and one or more non-whitespace chars
- `(?:\s+and\s+\S+)?` - an optional sequence of `and` enclosed with one or more whitespace chars and then one or more non-whitespace chars
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `sessions?` - `session` or `sessions`
- `\s+of\s+the` - one or more whitespaces, `of`, one or more whitespaces, `the`
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `Subsidiary\s+Body\s+for\s+Implementation` - `Subsidiary` + one or more whitespaces + `Body` + one or more whitespaces + `for` + one or more whitespaces + `Implementation`
  - `|` - or
  - `Conference\s+of\s+the\s+Parties` - `Conference` + one or more whitespaces + `of` + one or more whitespaces + `the` + one or more whitespaces + `Parties`
  - `|` - or
  - `subsidiary\s+bodies` -  `subsidiary` + one or more whitespaces + `bodies`
- `)` - end of the group.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for the `.*` at the beginning of your regex?

If I understand `findall` correctly, you don't need that